# PHP - How to write a line in text file if line already available in file then count the request

Tags: php

I want to write a PHP code which write a string line in text file if the line already available in text file then count the requests for example
text file contain:

```
red.apple:1
big.orange:1
green.banana:1
```

If some one request to add big.orange in file if its already available in file then count as `big.orange:2` if not available then write new line `big.orange:1`

after execution code text file

```
    red.apple:1
    big.orange:2
    green.banana:1
```

I've written the following code but not working.

```
<?PHP
$name = $_GET['fname']

$file = fopen('request.txt', "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");

if ($file) {
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $entry_array = explode(":",fgets($file));
        if ($entry_array[0] == $name) {
            $entry_array[1]==$entry_array[1]+1;
            fwrite($file, $entry_array[1]);
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
}    
else{
    fwrite($file, $name.":1"."\n");
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't know what your file is for, but if your application is the only thing that uses it, it would be much easier to store this as json. Then you just need to read the file, decode it and you you'll have an array with the data you can use.

Comment: You should also explain what _"not working"_ means. What actually happens?

Comment: Reading and writing to the same file isn't a good idea, you may find it better to read the file in/process/write new file.  As suggested using JSON is a good idea.

Comment: Btw, the above code would throw a syntax error since you're missing the `;` after `$_GET['fname']`.

Comment: in your logic, you forgot the code to add the new line if the file exists and the entry is not found. Also i suggest you use `intval($entry_array[1], 10)` to convert your number which comes as a string to integer. Also, in here `fwrite($file, $entry_array[1]);` you only write the number without the key and the `:`

Comment: And this: `$entry_array[1]==$entry_array[1]+1;` won't change anything. Using double `==` _compares_ two expressions, so that code just makes an comparison and ignores the result (which would just return `false`). It should be just one `=`, like this: `$entry_array[1] = $entry_array[1]+1;` or even shorter, just: `$entry_array[1]++;`

Comment: please send me json code. if possible

Comment: What do you mean _"send me json code"_? Do you mean how to do this using json instead?

Comment: yes i already try the above suggestions. please send me how to do this in json

Comment: I posted an answer using json. Let us know if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating your own format which you need to parse manually, you can simply use json.

Below is a suggestion about how it would work. It will add the requested `fname` value if it doesn't already exist and will also create the file if it doesn't already exists.

```
$name = $_GET['fname'] ?? null;

if (is_null($name)) {
    // The fname query param is missing so we can't really continue
    die('Got no name');
}

$file = 'request.json';

if (is_file($file)) {
    // The file exists. Load it's content
    $content = file_get_contents($file);

    // Convert the contents (stringified json) to an array
    $data = json_decode($content, true);
} else {
    // The file does not extst. Create an empty array we can use
    $data = [];
}

// Get the current value if it exists or start with 0
$currentValue = $data[$name] ?? 0;

// Set the new value
$data[$name] = $currentValue + 1;

// Convert the array to a stringified json object
$content = json_encode($data);

// Save the file
file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to use this format (like, this is some exam test or legacy), try the function:

```
     function touchFile($file, $string) {
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            if (is_writable(dirname($file))) {
                // create file (later)
                $fileData = "";
            } else {
                throw new ErrorException("File '".$file."' doesn't exist and cannot be created");
            }
        } else $fileData = file_get_contents($file);
        if (preg_match("#^".preg_quote($string).":(\d+)\n#m", $fileData, $args)) {
            $fileData = str_replace($args[0], $string.":".(intval($args[1])+1)."\n", $fileData);
        } else {
            $fileData .= $string.":1\n";
        }
        if (file_put_contents($file, $fileData)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because of the [mixed return value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-put-contents-returnvalues) of `file_put_contents` you should rather `return false !== file_put_contents($file, $fileData);`, though if you'd want the implicit casting, you could simply `return (bool) file_put_contents($file, $fileData)`.

Comment: Just a personal suggestion; Be consistent with using `{ }` for _all_ `if/else`. You're currently mixing with or without which makes the code harder to follow and read.